# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found Win7 X64

Tags: php, windows, apache

**Runtime environment:**
1: win7 x64;
2: [Apache 2.4.7](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/binaries/httpd-2.4.7-win64-VC11.zip)
3: mod_fcgid
4: [php 5.5.6 VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.6-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip)

**PHP.ini**

```
[COM_DOT_NET] 
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll 
com.allow_dcom = true
```

**Code:**

```
$word = new COM("word.application");
```

**Error:**
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in....

PS: I have already installed the .net framework and Visual C++ Redistributable Package

Comment: That DLL exists in the path expected?

Comment: php_com_dotnet.dll in the "ext" folder

Comment: Are any of your extensions loading?  Is the path set correctly?  You can verify with `php_info()`.  For what it's worth, I've also had problems with php.ini where unclosed quotes or unprintable characters in the file cause parts of the file to not load.  These kinds of errors don't typically show up in a log.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the extension_dir as an absolute path, it works!